# How to call another method during key frame animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation

For CAKeyframeAnimation, there are delegates for animation start and animation stop.  But I want to call a method in each time frame (to update some subview information on-the-fly).  Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is any way to do this. The closest you can come is running a timer with a very short period that queries the currently-visible layer properties by calling `-presentationLayer` on the layer and querying the result. However this is not guaranteed to match precisely with what's on-screen, as it effectively generates a copy of the model layer with the animations applied to the current time rather than querying the actual presentation layer used internally.